# Error 400 on Google Cloud Datastore query with sort and filter

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am writing a query for Google Cloud Datastore, wanting to find the entity with a certain "moduleID" and the highest number of "sessionID_tot".

```
$session_query = $datastore->query()
                        ->kind('Session')
                        ->filter('moduleID', '=', $module)
                        ->order('sessionID_tot', Query::ORDER_DESCENDING)
                        ->limit(1);
$session_result = $datastore->runQuery($session_query);
```

I get the following error.

> { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "no matching index found.
>   recommended index is:\n- kind: Session\n properties:\n - name:
>   moduleID\n - name: sessionID_tot\n direction: desc\n", "status":
>   "FAILED_PRECONDITION" } }

I have read all the limitations on queries [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#restrictions_on_queries), but can't seem to find a solution all the same. It works if I remove either the ordering or the filter for "moduleID". The properties I'm sorting and filtering are integers. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error, and linked to from the page you referenced.  You need to create a [composite index](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig) for that query.

Comment: Thanks! Had entirely missed the issue of composite indexes. This solved my problem. To update index.yaml file after manually adding composite indexes: `gcloud datastore indexes create [PATH-TO-INDEX.YAML]`